# 2D World Velocity to 2D Local Velocity

Tags: c++, math, vector, matrix, rotation

How do I calculate the local velocity of an object in X,Z coordinates when given North and East Velocity?

For Instance I have an Object moving 10mph North and 5mph East with a heading of 60 degrees.

How do I determine the forward velocity of the object and the lateral drift of the object?

This is written in a simplifed system that does not have matricies and quaterion libraries  so hoping to just use trig to be able to solve
Unfortunately its been a few years since I have done this so a little rusty on how to make this happen...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, if you're going at Vn north and Ve East your velocity vector is

```
V = (Ve, Vn)
```

and the direction of travel if you're measuring your heading as a bearing, b, clockwise from North is

```
F = (sin(H), cos(H))
```

from this we can also construct the vector pointing to your right

```
R = (cos(H), -sin(H))
```

where H is the heading converted to radians

```
H = b*PI/180.0
```

Then your speed in the direction you are facing is `speedForward = F.V` (the dot product) ie

```
speedForward = sin(H)*Ve + cos(H)*Vn
```

and similarly your speed drifting to your right is R.V

```
speedRight = cos(H)*Ve -sin(H)*Vn
```

obviously the forward velocity is speedForward*F and similarly for your right direction.

So in your example with V = (5, 10) and F = (sqrt(3)/2, 0.5)

Your forward speed is 9.33mph and your righthand drift speed is -6.16mph (ie you're drifting to the left at 6.16mph). Luckily the velocity measured in these coordinates has the same magnitude as in the original so it looks like we're ok. The sign on the sideways drift looks reasonable to me too from a picture.

Comment: giving it a shot now... THANKS!

Comment: Perfect - exactly what I need, it all makes sense, THANK you for clearly breaking this down, helps make it more concrete!